# Website Responsive Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I am in search of figuring out the correct script to make my desktop website mobile responsive.
As it currently stands, my website is recognized on mobile devices and directs to mobile website version.
What I am looking achieve is the correct script to redirect/switch my full site to my mobile site on a desktop browser window when you reduce(shrink) the browser window, making it responsive.
Here is my current script for mobile redirect:

```
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile) {    
    document.location = "my-mobile-site.html";    
}
```

Here is what I've come up with but obviously is not working:

```
var screen = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

if (screen.width <= 699) {          
    document.location = "my-mobile-site.html";
}
```

Am I close?

Comment: Is redirecting to a mobile version of the site making the site responsive? Why would you want to redirect to a mobile site if a desktop user resized the browser? clearly they aren't on a mobile device,

Comment: Per your second attempt, `screen` is a boolean value, it doesn't have a width...

Answer (score 0):

What I understand about your code is that you want to identify when a mobile device is detected, so as [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) says **screen** is a boolean value.

```
if (screen) {          
    document.location = "my-mobile-site.html";
}
```

Why do you return a html location?, instead, return your css file with other properties

```
if (screen) {
    document.location = "styles.css";
}
```

styles.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
    // here add your styles
}
```

sorry if I am wrong, I have never worked on creating mobile versions. I hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are serving a different content depending on the device, this is not longer considered as responsive design 
What you are trying to do, is a redirection to another page, and it's a very bad practice to deal with it Front Side: 
The redirection should be detected from the Back End, managed depending on the User Agent, and not the screensize.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent